# asp.net client developed with 4.0 SDK schould be converted in 2011 SDK (with support of Dynamics 4.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

I have developed an asp client with 4.0 SDK. To work with Dynamics 2011 I use 2007 endpoints (they are there for backward compatibility). But since last month is only "Office 365" authetification possible (for new clients) and this authentification method doesn't support 2007 endpoints. How can I convert my application spending so less time as possible? CRM Dynamics 4.0 schould be supported. May be I schould start a new Project instead of redevelop an old one?

Some info:

To authetificate a user I get from CRM CRMPassport and use it for crmService calls (crm online).

To work with endpoints i use a factory, which creates for me services:

```
CrmService crmService = CrmServiceHandlerFactory.GetInstance().Resolve<ICrmServiceHandler>().CreateCrmService(crmCallInfo);

BusinessEntityCollection userAttributesCol = 
    ((RetrieveMultipleResponse)crmService.Execute(qbaRequest)).BusinessEntityCollection;
```

I use metadata service the same way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start is to download the SDK and look at the examples.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Comment: I have already looked at examples, but if I will use the examples - my application will not be comaptible with CRM Dynamics 4.0

Comment: We have also dynamics 4.0 crm